# vertical spacing between images

Tags: html

I cut one image to three equal images and now I have it in the html code like this:

```
                        <img src="images/disclosure2_01.jpg" alt="Disclosure">
                        <img src="images/disclosure2_02.gif" alt="Disclosure2">
                        <img src="images/disclosure2_03.gif" alt="Disclosure3">
```

The images render at the website like this:
[image]

I want to know if its possible to remove that vertical spacing between the images and the images to look like one whole picture. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.
Remove the lines between them.

```
<img src="images/disclosure2_01.jpg" alt="Disclosure"><img src="images/disclosure2_02.gif" alt="Disclosure2"><img src="images/disclosure2_03.gif" alt="Disclosure3">
```

or tinker with css.

```
img { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The vertical space is because the property "display" is "inline", it is solved leaving the font size at zero, in its parent element. Or changing the display property to the images to "block".

```
<div style="font-size:0">
   <img src="images/disclosure2_01.jpg" alt="Disclosure">
   <img src="images/disclosure2_02.gif" alt="Disclosure2">
   <img src="images/disclosure2_03.gif" alt="Disclosure3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set each image's margin and padding to 0.

```
<img style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" src="..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any CSS adding margin/padding to the images?

Try adding this;

```
img { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the images' `vertical-align` to `middle`:

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x100/150/6ff">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x100/6ff/150">
```